# Ensure Fairness in Publisher/Subscriber Pattern

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, publish-subscribe

How can I ensure fairness in the Pub/Sub Pattern in e.g. kafka when one publisher produces thousands of messages, while all other producers are in a low digit of messages? It's not predictable which producer will have high activity.

It would be great if other messages from other producers don't have to wait hours just because one producer is very very active.

What are the patterns for that?  Is it possible with Kafka or another technology like Google PubSub? If yes, how?

Multiple partitions also doesn't work very well in that case, or I can see how.

Comment: You can publish any amount of messages to Kafka topic with any amount of producers. other producers don't have to wait until one producer is done.

Comment: @nipuna What I mean is this: Imagine I've one consumer processing the messages, then producers B messages are processed very late all the time, because producer A "spams" messages. So Producer B has to wait super long to see this thumbnails

Comment: Are they all producing to one stream/topic or Producer A sending to one topic and B sending to another?

Comment: @Lalit All to one. It's basically a thumbnail backlog for multiple clients.

Comment: Aha. Ok. I'm putting an answer here so let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'm only mentioning Kafka in my answer as I'm not entirely sure of other platforms such as Google Pub/Sub or AWS Kinesis. I presume there would be something similar in those as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kafka, you could utilise the concept of quotas to prevent a certain clients to monopolise the cluster resources.

There are 2 types of quotas that can be enforced:

1. Network bandwidth quotas
2. Request rate quotas

More detailed information on how these can be configured can be found in [the official documentation of Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/24/documentation.html#design_quotas).